# Is it possible to use for loop in the include tag?

Tags: twig

```
    {% include './partial/project.twig' with {'status': 'Past Project',
                                                          'statusClass': 'past',
                                                          'heroImage': "/dist/images/projects/project-south16th.jpg",
                                                          'logo': '/dist/images/logo-south16th.png',
                                                          'desc': '23 three- and four-bed townhomes',
                                                          'address': '15885 16 Avenue, South Surrey',
                                                          'showGallery': true,
                                                          'galleryID': 'south16th',
                                                          'link': '#',
                                                          'galleryImages': "
                                                     {% for i in range(1, 10) %}
                                                      <a data-fancybox='south16th' href='{{ theme.uri }}/dist/images/gallery/south16/{{ i }}.jpg'></a>
                                                      {% endfor %}
                                                           "

                                                          } %}
```

The above code is not valid because it seems like twig doesn't allow nested tag in the include tag? Or did I do something wrong?

Is there another way to achieve it? I would like to repeat this code X times and pass it to the template:

```
{% for i in range(1, 10) %}
<a data-fancybox='south16th' href='{{ theme.uri }}/dist/images/gallery/south16/{{ i }}.jpg'></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you would need to switch up to `embed` instead of `include`

<kbd>index.twig</kbd>

```
{% embed 'include.twig' with { 'theme': { 'uri' : 'https://www.example.com', 'pictures':  10, }, } %}
    {% block pictures %}
        {% for i in 1..theme.pictures %}
                <li><a data-fancybox='south16th' href='{{ theme.uri }}/dist/images/gallery/south16/{{ i }}.jpg'></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

<kbd>include.twig</kbd>

```
<h1>Include</h1>
<h2>{{ theme.uri }} - {{ theme.pictures }}</h2>
<ul>
    {% block pictures %}
    {% endblock %}
</ul>
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/edpks9)

---

*note: variables you'd define in `include.twig` will also be available inside the embed*